# Is this integral evaluated in any book?, how is it calculated?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

In a book I am reading it follows from a statement that

If $\nu \in (-1/2,1/2)$

$$\int\limits_0^\infty\left((1+x)^{\nu}-x^\nu\right)^2dx=\frac{\Gamma(\nu+1)^2}{\Gamma(2\nu+2)\sin(\pi(\nu+1/2))}-\frac{1}{2\nu+1}.$$

But there is no proof of this? Is the proof easy? Is it done in any books, do you have any links or hints?

The exact statement of the book is that for $H \in (0,1)$ we have

$$\left[\int\limits_0^\infty\left((1+x)^{H-\frac{1}{2}}-x^{H-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2dx+\frac{1}{2H}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\Gamma(H+1/2)}{(\Gamma(2H+1)\sin(\pi H))^{1/2}}.$$

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_b%C3%AAta in particular look at B(x,y)B(x+y,1-y) and the expression of it in term of $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Though are you sure that bound of integration is infinity, because this diverges ?

Comment: @zwim The integral converges: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084383/why-is-this-integral-well-defined-how-do-i-calculate-it-int-0-inftykxv

Comment: yep, I forgot about the little square, it is small.

Answer (score 1):

By integration by parts,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left((1+x)^\nu-x^\nu\right)^2\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}2\nu x\left((1+x)^\nu-x^\nu\right)\left(x^{\nu-1}-(1+x)^{\nu-1}\right)\,dx$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}2\nu x\left((1+x)^\nu-x^\nu\right)x^{\nu-1}\,dx = -\frac{2\, \Gamma(-1-2 \nu)\,\Gamma(2+\nu)}{\Gamma(-\nu)}$$
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}2\nu x\left((1+x)^\nu-x^\nu\right)(1+x)^{\nu-1}\,dx = \frac{1}{1+2 \nu}-\frac{2^{-1-2 \nu} \nu \Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\nu\right) \Gamma(1+\nu)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
follow from Euler's Beta function.